# Speed of DB2 query

Tags: db2, query-optimization, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a DB2 procedure that runs a very lengthy `SELECT` query (6 CTE's that touches about 5 or 6 different tables, some pivoting, few joins). I am logged into `System i Navigator` as an "admin" user. This user account has the authority to do basically everything. My personal username does not. So I log in as this to make it easier for myself.

When I run this procedure (by opening a SQL Script window and typing in `CALL Procedure_Name('Param1');`), the processing completes in 4 or 5 seconds.

My boss has logged into his `i Navigator` as his own username. His username has more powers than my personal account, but less than the admin one that I use. When he runs the same procedure in the same method that I do, it takes about 15-20 seconds to run it.

So my question is, does the username you are logged in as affect the speed in which a DB2 query runs? If so, what do I change to make the query run at the same speed for all users, preferably at the speed in which the admin account runs it?

Comment: You probably want to look at the query plans in both cases to compare them. Also,  System i (IBM i these days) has an ability to assign jobs to different workload groups with different hardware resources, so talk to your system administrator. If workload management is in place, there's nothing you can do on the client side to override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Run & Explain" from Run SQL Scripts (preferably the latest version included with [Access Client Solutions](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=isg3T1026805) (ACS) rather than the older IBM i Access for Windows i Navigator version)

Compare the results from the different user profiles.  Particularly the INI options section...it sounds as if the optimization goal may be different.
[image: INI Options]
 `*FIRSTIO` means the DB will pick the most efficient plan to return the first few records as quickly as possible; perfect if a user is waiting to see something on a screen.  `*ALLIO` means the DB will pick the most efficient plan for returning all the records;  perfect for a batch process (or a client app) that's going to retrieve all the records anyways.

Also look at the Environment Information section
[image: environment information]
That will show you if one user is running in different memory pool and/or workload group and/or there's a significant difference in memory available at the time one user is running.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take a look at these specs and mark yours as the answer if it points me in the right direction!